# Postgresql foreign key as primary not unique?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, relationship

So i have a table, that takes a nickname as foreign key and a id to form a primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE Character(
    Nickname TEXT,
    CONSTRAINT person_pk PRIMARY KEY(Nickname)
);
CREATE TABLE POSTING(
    PostingID BIGINT UNIQUE, 
    Nickname TEXT,
CONSTRAINT posting_fk FOREIGN KEY(Nickname) REFERENCES Person(Nickname),
    CONSTRAINT postings_pk PRIMARY KEY(PostingID, Nickname)
);
```

So far, so good. However, whenever i try to get now the primary key from posting, it tells me that: " there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "information"".

```
CREATE TABLE INFORMATION(
    InformationID BIGINT,
    PostingID BIGINT, 
    CONSTRAINT informations_fk FOREIGN KEY(PostingID) REFERENCES POSTING(PostingID),
    CONSTRAINT informations_pk PRIMARY KEY(InformationID, PostingID)
);


CREATE TABLE DATA(
    InformationID BIGINT,
    Link TEXT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT data_fk FOREIGN KEY(InformationID) REFERENCES INFORMATION(InformationID),
    CONSTRAINT datas_pk PRIMARY KEY(InformationID)
);
```

However, if i change in the table Information the InformationID to unique, the error disappears. Is that the correct way of doing things?

```
CREATE TABLE INFORMATION(
    InformationID BIGINT UNIQUE,
    PostingID BIGINT,
    CONSTRAINT informations_fk FOREIGN KEY(PostingID) REFERENCES POSTING(PostingID),
    CONSTRAINT informations_pk PRIMARY KEY(InformationID, PostingID)
);
```

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: A fk must reference a complete key, i.e. all its columns.

Comment: Okay so basically i also need to have a reference to the nickname in information, right?

Answer (score 1):

Either the primary key for `information` should be only `informationid`, or `data` must include `postingid` and the foreign key to `information` is defined on both columns.

Hard to say without knowing your data, but I suspect the former solution to be the correct one.

Comment: I see. Is it okay to have a foreign key in information, while using for the primary key only informationID? The posting has many informations, but one information belongs to exactly one post.

Comment: Yes, that's the normal way to do it. `informationid` uniquely identifies `information` (primary key), and it refers to a certain `posting` (foreign key).